# Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment'

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api

As google release new Places SDK. I am integrating it in one of my old project.

Before it was working perfectly with Google map places api but after addling new places API it shows me error

I have tried adding like below

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = 
  (AutocompleteSupportFragment) 
 getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
```

it is same as shown in developer site but still shows me error!

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment'
```

This is my layout:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="35dp" 
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:name= "com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"/>
```

Comment: I have added xml like this <fragment
                android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"/>